# Prove or disprove regarding comparison of two series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove or disprove.

If $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$$ is a convergent series of nonnegative numbers and $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$$ is a divergent series of nonnegative numbers, then $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$$ is dominated by $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$$

At first I was thinking this to be true and was using boundedness to prove, but something my professor said leads me to believe there is a counterexample that disproves this?

Comment: The question, as is, doesn't make sense. I think you are asking the following: if $0\leq a_n\leq b_n$ for all $n$ and $\sum b_n$ diverges, does $\sum a_n$ converge? The answer is certainly not.

Comment: I think OP meant "is a divergent series of nonnegative numbers, THEN".

Try the following as a counterexample. Let $a_1 = 2$ and $a_n = 0$ for $n > 1$. Let $b_n = 1/n$. Does $b_n$ dominate $a_n$?

Comment: Yes, as the absolute value of each term of a_n is less than the absolute value of each term of b_n, for n greater than 1?

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n=2^{-n}$ for all $n.$ Let $b_n=a_n/n$ when $n$ is odd. Let $b_n=1$ when $n$ is even. For any $K>0$ there are infinitely many $n$ for which $a_n>Kb_n.$

If you want $b_n\to 0$ then for even $n,$ change $b_n$ from $1$ to $1/n.$

Answer (score 0):

Knowing and using careful definitions is key to tackling these problems. A series $B=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ dominates another series $A=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n $ if for every $k\in\Bbb N, b_k>a_k$.

In other words, if there exists a pair of series that satisfy $A<\infty, B=\infty, a_1>b_1$ we have a contradiction.

The simplest way in my opinion (without using piecewise functions which I view as cheating) to find one is to use series you already know converge/diverge, such as $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  2^{-n}=\infty$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac 1n=\infty$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$
Compare the last two series

$$B=1+\frac12+\frac13+\ldots =\infty\tag1$$
$$A=1+\frac14+\frac19+\ldots =\frac{\pi^2}{6}\tag2$$

If we double $(2)$, we get $$\hat{A}=2+\frac 12 +\frac29+\ldots =\frac{\pi^2}{3}$$
which is still convergent and $\hat{a}_1=2>1=b_1$, contradicting the original statement

Comment: Does this contradict the definition of domination given in my textbook? (Please see bottom of pg. 89). https://alansinyal.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/method-of-real-analysis.pdf

Comment: It doesn't, but you should trust your stricter definition more than my broader one. I will rewrite my answer taking into account that definition